# Build errors for Avenger96 board with Arm Trusted Firmware-v2.2

Tags: ubuntu, arm, stm32, buildroot

I am building Linux images for Avenger96 board with Buildroot as Build system.

Steps I am doing:

1. make avenger96_defconfig
2. make

I am getting below errors:

```
/usr/bin/make -j1 O=/buildroot/output HOSTCC="/usr/bin/gcc" HOSTCXX="/usr/bin/g++"        syncconfig
make[1]: Entering directory '/buildroot'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/buildroot'
>>> arm-trusted-firmware v2.2 Building
PATH="/buildroot/output/host/bin:/buildroot/output/host/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local                     /bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" ENABLE_STACK_PROTECTOR=0 /usr/bin/make -j9 -C /buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2 DEBUG=1 CROSS_COMPILE="/buildroot/output     /host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-" STM32MP_SDMMC=1 AARCH32_SP=sp_min     DTB_FILE_NAME=stm32mp157a-avenger96.dtb PLAT=stm32mp1 ARM_ARCH_MAJOR=7 ARCH=aarch32 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2'
Including bl32/sp_min/sp_min.mk
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
Building stm32mp1
  LD      build/stm32mp1/debug/bl2/bl2.elf
  LD      build/stm32mp1/debug/bl32/bl32.elf
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: ./build/stm32mp1     /debug/bl32/psci_off.o: in function `psci_do_cpu_off':
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: /buildroot/output   /build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/lib/psci/psci_off.c:181: undefined reference to    `__stack_chk_fail'
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: /buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/lib/psci/psci_off.c:181: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: ./build/stm32mp1  /debug/bl2/stm32_hash.o./build/stm32mp1/debug/bl32/psci_suspend.o: in function `: in    function `psci_cpu_suspend_start':
stm32_hash_update/buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/lib   /psci/psci_suspend.c:':
272: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld/buildroot/output   /build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/crypto/stm32_hash.c:: 236: undefined reference   to `/buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/lib  /psci/psci_suspend.c:__stack_chk_fail'
272: undefined reference to `/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: __stack_chk_guard/buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/crypto/stm32_hash.c:'
236: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: ./build/stm32mp1    /debug/bl2/stm32_hash.o: in function `stm32_hash_final':
 /buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/crypto/stm32_hash.c:263:    undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: /buildroot/output  /build   /arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/crypto/stm32_hash.c:263: undefined reference   to   `__stack_chk_guard'
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: ./build/stm32mp1    /debug/bl2/stm32_hash.o: in function `stm32_hash_register':
 /buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/crypto/stm32_hash.c:330:   undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
 /buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: /buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/crypto/stm32_hash.c:330: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
 /buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: /buildroot/output   /host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: ./build/stm32mp1/debug    /bl2/io_stm32image.o: in function `stm32image_partition_size':
 /buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/io/io_stm32image.c:243: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: /buildroot/output   /build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/io/io_stm32image.c:243: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
 /buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld: ./build/stm32mp1/debug/bl2/io_stm32image.o: in function `stm32image_partition_read':
 /buildroot/output/build/arm-trusted-firmware-v2.2/drivers/st/io/io_stm32image.c:354:  undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
```

and much more

I have attached complete log file. I am not understanding the reason for these "undefined reference to " issues. Can someone please let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 20.04

[ATF log_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmtHJ.png) [ATF log_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc8O2.png) [ATF log_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEomR.png)

Comment: This is related to gcc flag `-fno-stack-protector`. I think you made a build without adding "ENABLE_STACK_PROTECTOR=0" then it failed. Then you might have made some changes then resumed the build with "ENABLE_STACK_PROTECTOR=0". If this is the case, I suggest to make a clean build with whatever flags you are building without mix-and-match.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. Tbh, I did not enable/disable any such flags. I tried `make clean all`, but same issue again. So, should I set "ENABLE_STACK_PROTECTOR=0"? Can you please show me how to do this?

Comment: Try `make clean`. Then build with whatever `make` command line your platform suggests you to use. I don't have specific build command knowledge of the platform that you are using.

Comment: I tried with ATF version v2.5 instead of v2.2. Ran `make clean` and then `make`. Now build is successful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed by Buildroot commit [ccac9a5bbbd7374187a0f0017101ece0c202851d](https://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/commit/?id=ccac9a5bbbd7374187a0f0017101ece0c202851d) which is included in the 2021.11 release (i.e. the release that was current when this question was posted).